# JSON for tree view of employees

Tags: c#, treeview, console-application

I have list of students that needs to be loaded as tree structure.

The following is my Employee class

```
public class Employee
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        public int Order { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my tree view class which I want to display to the user

```
public class Tree
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool isSelected { get; set; }

        public List<Tree> children { get; set; }

    }
```

Based on the employee list the json should be displayed something like this

[image]

The below code is giving me duplicates for each parent id and not giving the expected result.

```
var groupedUsers = result.GroupBy(t=>t.ParentId).SelectMany(t=>t.ToList());
            foreach (var item in groupedUsers)
            {

                if (item.ParentId == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    treeData.Add(new Tree()
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        children = new List<Tree>(),
                        isSelected = item.IsDefault,
                        Name = item.Name
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    var parent = treeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == item.ParentId);
                    if (parent != null)
                    {
                        parent.children.Add(new Tree()
                        {
                            Id = item.Id,
                            children = new List<Tree>(),
                            isSelected = item.IsDefault,
                            Name = item.Name
                        });
                        treeData.Add(parent);
                    }


                }
            }
```

Update: With Robert's answer I was able to get going but it is still duplicates
the end json could be found here [Tree JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=79db783ce30d452e89e98a04f8a442ef) So I updated the code to something like this to eliminate duplicates. But it is not working I guess I am missing some thing in recursion?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Dinesh\source\repos\Tests\Tests\Employee.json");
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(text);


            var groupedUsers = result.GroupBy(t => t.ParentId).SelectMany(t => t.ToList()).OrderBy(t=>t.Order).ToList();



            foreach (var item in groupedUsers)
            {
                AddEmployee(item, null, groupedUsers, treeData);

            }
        }


        static Tree AddEmployee(Employee parentEmployee, Employee childEmployee, List<Employee> groupedUsers, List<Tree> newTreeData)
        {

            if (parentEmployee.ParentId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                var root = new Tree()
                {
                    Id = parentEmployee.Id,
                    children = new List<Tree>(),
                    isSelected = parentEmployee.IsDefault,
                    Name = parentEmployee.Name
                };
                treeData.Add(root);
                return root;
            }
            else
            {
                var parent = treeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == parentEmployee.ParentId);
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    var parentItem = groupedUsers.Single(x => x.Id == parentEmployee.ParentId);
                    var currentTree = newTreeData.SelectMany(t => t.children).Where(y => y.Id == parentEmployee.ParentId).ToList();
                    parent = AddEmployee(parentItem, parentEmployee, groupedUsers, currentTree);
                }
                if (childEmployee != null)
                {
                    var childsParent = newTreeData.Where(y=>y.Id == childEmployee.ParentId).First();
                    return childsParent;

                }
                var child = newTreeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == parentEmployee.Id);
                if (child != null)
                    return child;
                child = new Tree()
                {
                    Id = parentEmployee.Id,
                    children = new List<Tree>(),
                    isSelected = parentEmployee.IsDefault,
                    Name = parentEmployee.Name
                };
                parent.children.Add(child);
                return child;

            }

        }
```

Comment: I think your `treeData.Add(parent);` line is not correct. You already added it somewhere, because you found it with `var parent = treeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == item.ParentId);`. So `if (parent != null)` just add the child, `else` add the parent to `treeData`.

Comment: This line make no sense : var parent = treeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == item.ParentId);  You should not be going to the root of the tree from grandchildren.  You do not need a parent.  You are only working with current node and children.  The children should be added to "t".  So you should have t.children.Add(new Tree()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: I think you should use recurrency. You may loose children if parent is not found.
Some draft may look like this:

```
var treeData = new List<Tree>();

var groupedUsers = result.GroupBy(t => t.ParentId).SelectMany(t => t.ToList());

foreach (var item in groupedUsers)
{
    AddEmployee(item);
}

Tree AddEmployee(dynamic item) 
{

    if (item.ParentId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        var root = new Tree()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            children = new List<Tree>(),
            isSelected = item.IsDefault,
            Name = item.Name
        };
        treeData.Add(root);         
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        var parent = Find(item.ParentId, treeData);
        if (parent == null)
        {               
            var parentItem = groupedUsers.Single(x => x.Id == item.ParentId);
            parent = AddEmployee(parentItem );              
        }

        var child = Find(item.Id, treeData);
        if (child != null)
           return child;
        child = new Tree()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            children = new List<Tree>(),
            isSelected = item.IsDefault,
            Name = item.Name
        };
        parent.children.Add(child );            
        return child;

    }       
}
Tree Find(Guid item, List<Tree> tree)
{
    var parent = tree?.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == item);
    if (parent != null)
    {
        return parent;
    }
    if (tree != null)
    {           
        foreach(var t in tree)
        {
           parent = Find(item, t?.children);
           if (parent != null)
               return parent;
        }
    }
    return null;        
}
```

UPDATE: Added Find method. You need to search through whole tree

Answer (score 0):

Because it gets better formated as in the comments.

Your line `treeData.Add(parent);` always adds the item - 
regardless of whether it already was added or not.

```
var parent = treeData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == item.ParentId);
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.children.Add(new Tree()
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        children = new List<Tree>(),
        isSelected = item.IsDefault,
        Name = item.Name
    });
    // do not add the parent again here
}
else 
{
    // add the parent only if was not found above
    // TODO parent = new Tree(...);
    treeData.Add(parent);
}
```